# Hakka song: problem translating a bit

Tags: translation, topolect, lyrics, hakka

**Full song lyrics with transliteration and translation attempt**

The spelling is not something I want to discuss here. Indeed, I discussed it [here](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/08/on-my-spelling-and-transliteration-of.html). The transliteration is that given by [Minhakka](http://minhakka.ling.sinica.edu.tw), plus the tones and sounds given by the admin of [the Hakka Verse facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/hakkaverse) in case of words not to be found on Minhakka.

> 难忘记
>   两人相爱每日都欢喜
>   恁<sup>1</sup>开心                                <sup>1</sup>恁: 很
>   行街牵手唻<sup>2</sup>都去                  <sup>2</sup>唻: 哪儿
>   还将婚姻提
>   永远不分离
>   齐家<sup>3</sup>发誓心不移                 <sup>3</sup>齐家: 大家
>   结连理
>   
>   一下变心
>   无<sup>4</sup>讲分手个<sup>5</sup>道理               <sup>4</sup>无: 没(有)   <sup>5</sup>个: 的
>   涯<sup>6</sup>伤心                               <sup>6</sup>涯: 我
>   人相思病係<sup>7</sup>难医                 <sup>7</sup>係: 是
>   夜夜醉么人<sup>8</sup>知                    <sup>8</sup>么人: 谁
>   过去毋<sup>9</sup>想提                        <sup>9</sup>毋: 不
>   每日都想着<sup>10</sup>汝<sup>11</sup>              <sup>10</sup>想着: 想到   <sup>11</sup>汝: 你
>   人痴迷
>   涯<sup>12</sup>深深爱汝<sup>13</sup>      <sup>12</sup>涯: 我   <sup>13</sup>汝: 你
>   爱亲口讲汝<sup>14</sup>知                 <sup>14</sup>汝: 你
>
> Nân mông-kì
>   Lióng-nyîn siong-òi mui nyit tu fon-hí
>   Àn khoi-sím
>   Hâng kai khen-shíu nái tu hì
>   Hân tsiong fun-yin thì
>   Yún-yén put fun-lî
>   Tshê-ka fat-shì sim put yî
>   Ket liên-li
>   
>   Yit-hà pièn-sim
>   Mô kóng fun-shíu kài thàu-li
>   Ngâi shong-sim
>   Nyîn siong-sii-phiàng hè nân-yì
>   Yá-yá tsùi mài-nyîn ti
>   Kwò-hì m sióng thì
>   Mui nyit tu sióng tó nyî
>   Nyîn chi-mî
>   Ngâi chim-chim òi nyî
>   Òi tshin-héu kóng nyî ti
>
> It's hard to forget
>   When we two loved each other and were happy every day,
>   Very happy,
>   We walked holding hands and went everywhere,
>   We also brought up marriage,
>   We would never break up,
>   The two of us (?) had sworn our hearts wouldn't move
>   (??)
>   
>   Suddenly [you] changed your mind,
>   Didn't say your reason for breaking up
>   I am sad
>   Lovesickness is hard to cure
>   Each night I get drunk, who knows?
>   I don't want to bring up the past
>   I think of you every day
>   Infatuated
>   I love you deeply
>   You should personally tell [me] you know (or "I should personally tell you [so you will] know"?)

**Question(s)**

1. The main point is that I (and the admin of Hakka Verse as well) am uncertain about how to translate `结连理`; what is the exact meaning and the best way to translate this part?
2. Secondly, is it a good idea to interpret `齐家` as `everyone` (which is possible in Hakka, as per [Minhakka's entry](http://minhakka.ling.sinica.edu.tw/bkg/hakyin/detail.php?hoan=47742&mode=1), or should I take it as a Mandarin word, hence translate to `manage the family`? Said admin suggests the spelling `结恋了 | ket-lièn-lí`; is that it? What would that mean?
3. Finally, which of the two translations of the last line is the correct one in this context?

Comment: Why that downvote though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 结连理 means "get married" or "become loving husband and wife"

'结' short for '结成'(form)

'连理' came from '[连理枝](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%BF%9E%E7%90%86%E6%9E%9D/59549)' (intertwined trees)

> *连理枝是指两棵树的枝干合生在一起的一种植物。连理枝又称相思树、夫妻树、生死树，比喻夫妻恩爱。连理枝在自然界已相当罕见。*
>
> '[连理枝](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%BF%9E%E7%90%86%E6%9E%9D/59549) (intertwined trees) refers to two trees planted next to each other and their branches intertwined as they grow. Also known as lovesick tree, husband and wife tree, life and death tree (two trees that live together, die together). Metaphor for **husband and wife love**. It is quite rare in nature.
>
> '连' means 'linked'; '理' short for '紋理' which means 'pattern'; '连理' refers to the pattern of the intertwined branches.
>
> Related phrase: "在天愿为比翼鸟, 在地愿为连理枝"

I suggest translate it as "t**ill death do us part**" which is a marriage vow perfectly match the spirit of 结连理 (become intertwined trees) - 连理枝 stay together for life.

2. '齐家' in this context is a pronoun similar to '大家' in Cantonese (both of us)
3. '爱' might be a typo of '我' in '爱亲口讲汝知'. It could be '我亲口讲汝知' (I personally tell you); If 爱 is not a typo, then the phrase means " Love, I personally tell you" with 'love' as the topic and 'I personally tell you' as the comment.

Comment: Concerning 1., note that the expression is "till death do **us** part". Concerning 3., it could be a typo, but not for "I", because in the video you clearly hear "oi", so it matches neither the typical Hakka 涯 | ngâi nor a supposed 我 | (ng)ô; the reason of my second interpretation is that 爱, in Hakka, is often used as 要 in mandarin (cfr. Min Nan 欲 for that matter).

Comment: I guess this sense of 大家 is Cantonese-only, and not Mandarin, right? (In comment above, Min Nan 欲 is read b(u)ėh)